# Empty CursorLoader after returning from child activity

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

My activity has two loaders: the first one fetches some metadata and the other one uses these data in a query to get actual data for ListView. So when I start this activity everything works fine. Then I start child activity to edit/create list element and when I press the back button I see the first activity again but this time CursorLoader (first one) returns an empty cursor (not null, just getCount() = 0). And this happens only on pressing the back button. If I finish the child activity everything is fine as if I started the first activity for the first time.

Here's my activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_routine_journal);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routine_journal_listView);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        routineId = i.getLongExtra("routineId", -1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_add_routine_item) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RoutineItemEditActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("routineId", routineId);
            i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("fields", fields);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;

        if (id == FIELDS) {
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                    TrackerContentProvider.CONTENT_FIELD_URI,
                    FieldTable.getColumns(),
                    FieldTable.COLUMN_ROUTINE + " = ?",
                    new String[]{routineId + ""},
                    null);

        } else if (id == JOURNAL) {
            String query = getQuery();
            Log.d("VK", "query=" + query);
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                    TrackerContentProvider.CONTENT_ROUTINE_ITEM_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    query);
        }

        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(FIELDS, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor data) {

        int loaderId = loader.getId();

        if (loaderId == FIELDS) {
            storeFields(data);
        } else if (loaderId == JOURNAL) {
            cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    private void storeFields(Cursor c) {

        if (c == null) return;

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            FieldItem fieldItem;
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(FieldTable.COLUMN_ID));
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(FieldTable.COLUMN_NAME));
                String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(FieldTable.COLUMN_TYPE));
                boolean active = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(FieldTable.COLUMN_ACTIVE)) != 0;
                long rid = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(FieldTable.COLUMN_ROUTINE));

                fieldItem = new FieldItem(id, name, type, active, rid);
                fields.add(fieldItem);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        cursorAdapter = new RoutineCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), null, 0);
        cursorAdapter.setFields(fields);
        listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(JOURNAL, null, this);
    }
```

UPDATE: Since I noticed that everything works fine when I use finish() on the child activity I tried to override default action bar's back button behaviour in child activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
}
```

This does the trick but it doesn't seem as a correct way. Any ideas?

BTW: by the back button I mean the one in Activity's action bar (not the back button in system navigation bar).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(JOURNAL, null, this);
```

to

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(JOURNAL, null, this);
```

because the loader has already created so it is not created again, it must restart.

Comment: As I said it has TWO loaders, and here you're pointing at the second one which works fine if the first one returns data. The problem here is that the first one doesn't return data...

Comment: also if the first one reloads again you have a problem with second one, add `.forceload();` to the first one.